# Como converter valores em porcentagem de uma coluna "total" em pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Olá! Estou aprendendo sobre Python e Numpy, porém estou com dificuldades em trabalhar com porcentagens. Considerando que a coluna total corresponde a 100%, como faço para obter as respectivas porcentagens de cada coluna com suas linhas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia, pf coloque o código que já tentou e/ou uma amostra dos dados (.csv talvez) para facilitar a vida a quem o tentar ajudar. Nunca coloque imagens pois isso dificulta o copy/paste obviamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta isto:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['Data Analisis', 'Machine Learning', 'Data Visualisation', 'Big Data', 'Deep Learning', 'Data Journalism'],
    'b': [1688, 1629, 1340, 1332, 1263, 429],
    'c': [444, 477, 734, 729, 770, 1081],
    'd': [60, 74, 102, 127, 136, 610],
})

df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1) # somar valores da linha, caso nao tenha isto logo a partida

# calcular percentagens
df['b %'] = df['b']/df['Total']*100
df['c %'] = df['c']/df['Total']*100
df['d %'] = df['d']/df['Total']*100
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
                    a     b     c    d  Total        b %        c %        d %
0       Data Analisis  1688   444   60   2192  77.007299  20.255474   2.737226
1    Machine Learning  1629   477   74   2180  74.724771  21.880734   3.394495
2  Data Visualisation  1340   734  102   2176  61.580882  33.731618   4.687500
3            Big Data  1332   729  127   2188  60.877514  33.318099   5.804388
4       Deep Learning  1263   770  136   2169  58.229599  35.500231   6.270171
5     Data Journalism   429  1081  610   2120  20.235849  50.990566  28.773585
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/ImperfectFilthyOpensource)

Comment: Muito obrigado! É este tipo de operação que eu gostaria de fazer, e não estava conseguindo, Miguel!